# What is a good way to measure performance and usage on my webserver

Tags: webserver, usage-statistics

We have an internal web server (intranet) and starting next week we will be under a heavy load. I need to monitor things like users online, page hits, wait time. I can't use outside sites to measure this. I need something that can be loaded internally.

Comment: What webserver are you running - apache, nginx, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [siege](http://www.joedog.org/)
you can collect some urls using proxy tool or import your google webmasters sitemap extraciton.
then you can run some simluations, specify clients, delys etc.
you can also, if you have external proxies, simulate different users.